# Vert.x Reactive DB2 Client: How to pass DB2 specific JDBC-Properties?

Tags: db2, vert.x

My intention is to use the specific client re-route Feature([see here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/faq-how-configure-jdbc-driver-automatic-client-re-route)) of the DB2 JDBC Driver. Therefore I have to pass some specific JDBC properties to the [Reactive DB2 Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-db2-client/java/#_connecting_to_db2) connection configuration.

When I try to pass the properties via:

```
DB2ConnectOptions connectOptions =
  new DB2ConnectOptions()
    .setPreparedStatementCacheMaxSize(dbConf.getPreparedStatementCacheMaxSize())
    .setCachePreparedStatements(dbConf.isCachePreparedStatements())
    .setPort(6000)
    .setHost("host1")
    .setDatabase(dbConf.getDatenbankName())
    .setUser(dbConf.getBenutzer())
    .setPassword(dbConf.getPasswort()) // won't take affect
    .addProperty("enableClientAffinitiesList", "1") // won't take affect
    .addProperty("clientRerouteAlternateServerName", "host2") // won't take affect
    .addProperty("clientRerouteAlternatePortNumber", "5000"); // won't take affect

// Create the pooled sqlClient
var dbPool =
  DB2Pool.client(
    vertx,
    connectOptions,
    new PoolOptions()
      .setMaxSize(dbConf.getPoolSize())
      .setConnectionTimeout(dbConf.getConnectionTimeout())
      .setPoolCleanerPeriod(dbConf.getPoolCleanerPeriod())
      .setIdleTimeout(dbConf.getIdleTimeout()));
```

The properties doesn't be passed thought to the JDBC-Driver.

Does anybody know, if "io.vertx.db2client.DB2ConnectOptions#addProperty" is the right place to pass JDBC specific properties to the DB2 Driver
or is this functionality for the [Reactive DB2 Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-db2-client/java/#_connecting_to_db2) not available?

I hope anybody can help, kind regards :-)